# Random sample the model scores into 4 groups with a similar distribution in python

Tags: python, pandas, distribution

I have a dataset with model scores ranging from 0 to 1. The table looks like below:

```
| Score |
| ----- |
| 0.55  |
| 0.67  |
| 0.21  |
| 0.05  |
| 0.91  |
| 0.15  |
| 0.33  |
| 0.47  |
```

I want to randomly divide these scores into 4 groups. `control`, `treatment 1`, `treatment 2`, `treatment 3`. `control` group should have 20% of the observations and the rest 80% has to be divided into the other 3 equal sized groups. However, i want the distribution of scores in each group to be the same. How can i solve this using python?

PS: This is just a representation of the actual table, but it will have a lot more observations than this.

Comment: If you're randomly splitting the data into groups the distribution in each group _should_ be statistically indistinguishable so you really shouldn't need to enforce that constraint. Any other methods to cherry pick the splits so that things so that things are _exactly_ the same (or as close as possible) won't really be random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.random.choice` to set random groups with defined probabilities, then `groupby` to split the dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
group = np.random.choice(['control', 'treatment 1', 'treatment 2', 'treatment 3'],
                          size=len(df),
                          p=[.2, .8/3, .8/3, .8/3])

dict(list(df.groupby(pd.Series(group, index=df.index))))
```

possible output (each value in the dictionary is a DataFrame):

```
{'control':    Score
 2   0.21
 5   0.15,
 'treatment 1':    Score
 7   0.47,
 'treatment 2':    Score
 1   0.67
 3   0.05,
 'treatment 3':    Score
 0   0.55
 4   0.91
 6   0.33}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate numbers:

```
import random
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,10):
    n = random.uniform(0,1)
    randomlist.append(n)

randomlist
```

---

Split into chunks: - so in this case:

```
categories = 4;
length = round(len(randomlist)/categories)
```

---

```
chunks = [randomlist[x:x+length] for x in range(0, len(randomlist), length)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using lists just for illustration. For each number you throw a five-sided dice and if it's 1 it goes into control. If it's not 1 you throw a 3 sided dice (yeah, probably there's no such thing ;) ) and that determines the treatment group.

```
import random
list = [0.23, 0.034, 0.35, 0.75, 0.92, 0.25, 0.9]   
control = []
treatment1 = []
treatment2 = []
treatment3 = []
for score in list:
    dice = random.randint(1,5)
    print(dice, 'is dice')
    if dice == 1:
        control.append(score)
    else:
        seconddice = random.randint(1,3)
        print(seconddice, 'is second dice')
        if seconddice == 1:
            treatment1.append(score)
        elif seconddice == 2:
            treatment2.append(score)
        else: # seconddice == 3:
            treatment3.append(score)
    
print(control, 'is control')
print(treatment1, 'is treatment1')
print('and so on')
```

I made a short list to test and the results were

```
5 is dice
1 is second dice
1 is dice
4 is dice
3 is second dice
5 is dice
2 is second dice
1 is dice
5 is dice
1 is second dice
3 is dice
1 is second dice
[0.034, 0.92] is control
[0.23, 0.25, 0.9] is treatment1
and so on
```

The larger the data set, the better your distribution will be.

Comment: This seems a bit complicated to be practical ;)